# how to include wildcard characters in cp command

Tags: bash, scripts, cp

I want to use cp command in a script where the path structure has variable folder name.

For example:

folder structure:

```
Workspace/unzipped_workspace/artifactory/my_folder123243/files
```

Here `my_folder123243` is not constant and `my_folder*` is the only folder in `artifactory` folder.

I tried using

```
cp -f Workspace/unzipped_workspace/artifactory/*/files ./
```

But this is giving me error

```
cp cannot stat Workspace/unzipped_workspace/artifactory/*/files: no such file or directory
```

How can I use `cp` command in my script when I have variable folder name?

Comment: That suggests the shell can't find any files matching that path pattern. Does `ls Workspace/unzipped_workspace/artifactory/*/files` find anything? Is the "Workspace" directory in the directory you're running this command from?

Comment: By not including your script this will go nowhere. Please provide it so someone can explain what you did wrong. 1 thing: you do not use a * in a directory. you use "find" or a loop for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using `find` + `cp`:

```
find Workspace/unzipped_workspace/artifactory -name files -exec cp {} ./ \;
```

This command does not need `*` since it will match all files named `files` in `Workspace/unzipped_workspace/artifactory`